# Default selection on Shopify multi selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

today I come with this issue:

I am using Shopify's default javascript for multi selectors for the product variables:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", { product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected: selectCallback });
});
```

if I have variables for, say socks defined like this:

```
XS / Pair
S / Pair
M / Pair
L / Pair

XS / Single
S / Single
M / Single
L / Single
```

what I want to know is if there's a way to set a variant selected by default, for example, if I'm on a collection called "Single Socks" the Single option is checked, and if I'm on a collection called "Pair of socks", the Pair variant is checked.

Is there any way to achieve this without trying to alter the very fabric of the universe?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I did was triggering the change with jQuery like this:

```
{% if collection.url contains "pair" %}
    $('#product-select-option-1').val("Pair").trigger('change');
{% else %}
    $('#product-select-option-1').val("Single").trigger('change');
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You notice that **Pair** and **Single** are options? Well, it turns out that Shopify still renders select elements with those options being part of the fabric of the universe. Your challenge is to simply wait till those select elements are all setup, and then select the one you want, by first off finding the one that matches your option, and then the specific option value.

It really boils down to nothing more than checking some select elements with a plan... that Shopify code is awkward sure... but in the end, it is totally hackable.

Comment: thanks, in the end I did it in a -not so- elegant way, but effective.